# pybind11 zoned datetime conversions

Tags: python, c++, datetime, timezone

I'm currently looking for a solution to handle zoned datetime conversions between python and C++ using pybind11.  In pybind11/chrono.h there support for such conversions with naive datetime using the built in python datetime objects and the std library time_point objects; however, there is explicitly no handling for the associated timezones of the python datetime.datetime objects.  I'm wondering if any work has been done in pybind11 to more fully support these conversions with consideration for timezones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the time of this post, there is no way within CPython datetime API to handle zoned times.  The best option I've found was to wrap [date](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) and effectively define an entirely new date time library in python which can pass zoned times to C++

Answer (score 3):

The [pybind11/chrono.h](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/blob/master/include/pybind11/chrono.h) binding is specifically to provide conversion between `std::chrono` and python's `datetime`.  Since `std::chrono` does not have time zone support, then neither can the binding.  In other words - what would you bind it ***to***?

One good answer might be [Howard Hinnant's date.h and tz.h libraries](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) - which are indeed being [proposed for standardization](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/d0355r5.html).  However, this hasn't happened yet.

Even without standardization, one might be able to write such bindings and include them in pybind - though I am not aware of anyone doing that.  If you are interested, it would be good to create an issue to discuss with the pybind maintainer's [in their issue tracker](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues).

Comment: As you've pointed out, this is purely a question of which set of timezone aware objects to bind.  I agree that the best candidate at this time would be Howard Hinnant's library.  I'll raise the issue as you suggested; however, I would assume there would be reluctance add an additional dependency for that Howard Hinnant's library.  Ideally, someone has already written these bindings and they can simply be popularized.  If they don't seem to exist, I will certainly look into doing this myself.